# React Router Link changes URL but doesn't render Component - Rest Countries API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am building an app following the Rest Countries API challenge from frontendmentor (https://www.frontendmentor.io/challenges/rest-countries-api-with-color-theme-switcher-5cacc469fec04111f7b848ca). I have run into a problem. When clicking on the router link in countryDetail.js, the url changes but the component doesn't get re-rendered unless the page is refreshed.

CountryDetails.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {CountryDetailStyles, ImgContainer, CountryInfo, CountryInfoDetails, CountryDetailsWrapper, CountryInfoDetailsInner, CountryBorders, LinkWrapper} from "../styles/CountryDetailStyles";

function CountryDetail({match, history}) {

  const [item, setItem] = useState([]);
  const [allCountries, setAllCountries] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
     fetchItem();
     setBorderCountries();
  }, []);

  const fetchItem = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${match.params.name}?fullText=true`);
    setItem(response.data)
  }

  const setBorderCountries = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all`);
    setAllCountries(response.data)
  }

  // get borders full name using alpha3code
  const getBorderCountryName = (allCountries, border) => {
    const matchingCountry = allCountries.find(country => {
      return country.alpha3Code === border;
    })

     return matchingCountry.name;
  }
    
  return (
       <CountryDetailStyles>
           <Link className="country-links" to={"/"}>
             <LinkWrapper>
             <p><i className="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>Go Back</p>
             </LinkWrapper>
             </Link>
           {
            item.length > 0 && item.map(i => (   
               <CountryDetailsWrapper>           
               <ImgContainer flag={i.flag}>
               </ImgContainer>
               <CountryInfo>
                   <h1>{i.name}</h1>
                   <CountryInfoDetails>
                       <CountryInfoDetailsInner>
                       <p><span>Native Name: </span>{i.nativeName}</p>
                       <p><span>Population: </span>{i.population.toLocaleString()}</p>
                       <p><span>Region: </span>{i.region.length > 0 ? i.region : 'N/A'}</p>
                       <p><span>Sub Region: </span>{i.subregion.length > 0 ? i.subregion : 'N/A'}</p>
                       <p><span>Capital: </span>{i.capital.length > 0 ? i.capital : 'N/A'}</p>
                       </CountryInfoDetailsInner>
                       <CountryInfoDetailsInner className="second">
                       <p><span>Top Level Domain: </span>{i.topLevelDomain}</p>
                       <p><span>Currencies: </span>{i.currencies[0].name}</p>
                       <p><span>Languages: </span>{i.languages.map(lang => lang.name).join(", ")}</p>
                       </CountryInfoDetailsInner>
                   </CountryInfoDetails>
                   <CountryBorders>
                       <p><span>Border Countries:</span></p>
                    {allCountries.length > 0 && i.borders.map(border => {
                      const borderName = getBorderCountryName(allCountries, border);
                      return (<Link to={`/country/${borderName.toLowerCase()}`}><button>{borderName}</button></Link>)
                    })}
                   </CountryBorders>
               </CountryInfo>
               </CountryDetailsWrapper>
           ))
           }
        </CountryDetailStyles>
  )
}

export default CountryDetail;
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import { lightTheme, darkTheme } from './styles/themes';
import { GlobalStyles } from './styles/global';
import { useState } from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import { useDarkMode } from './hooks/useDarkMode';
import CountryList from './components/CountryList';
import CountryDetail from './components/CountryDetail';
import {Route} from "react-router-dom";


function App() {
  const [theme, toggleTheme] = useDarkMode();
  const themeMode = theme === 'dark' ? darkTheme : lightTheme;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ThemeProvider theme={themeMode}>
        <GlobalStyles />
        <Navbar navTheme={theme} toggleTheme={toggleTheme} />
        <Route exact path="/" component={CountryList} />
        <Route exact path="/country/:name" component={CountryDetail} />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
   
  );
}

export default App;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

 
reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: Could you try wrapping your routes in a [`<Switch>`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch)?

Comment: didn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: should that second route have an "exact" on it?

Comment: removed the exact, still didn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The issue seems to be that you are ***already*** on the `"/country/:name"` path and are clicking to visit ***another*** country. The router correctly updates the URL in the address bar, but because `CountryDetail` is already mounted it neglects to recompute the `item` and `allCountries` state. This is because the `useEffect` hook only runs once when the component mounts.

## Solution

The `name` param (`match.params.name`) is *actually* a dependency for the GET requests, it should be added to the `useEffect` hook's dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
 fetchItem();
 setBorderCountries();
}, [match.params.name]);

const fetchItem = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(
    `https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${match.params.name}?fullText=true`
  );
  setItem(response.data);
}
```

### Suggestion

It seems `allCountries` *doesn't* have this dependency, so I recommend splitting it into its own `useEffect` hook with empty dependency array so you fetch this data only once when the component mounts.

```
useEffect(() => {
 setBorderCountries();
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
 fetchItem();
}, [match.params.name]);
```